# Will the ECDSA with SHA-3 implementation be quantum-proof?

Tags: hash, dsa, sha-3, post-quantum-cryptography

I know, that ECDSA could be broken by quantum computers, but since there is post-quantum hash function SHA-3, does not this make the digital signature resistant to them?

Comment: A chain is only as strong as its weakest link

Comment: @CodesInChaos: But a chain locked in a box is as strong as the box. You need to know which metaphor is appropriate to a situation, before applying it to reach a conclusion. (As it happens, yours is in this case...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  Anyone who can compute elliptic-curve discrete logs, such as an adversary with a quantum computer powerful enough to run Shor's algorithm, can immediately recover an ECDSA private key and forge arbitrary signatures of their choice.  It doesn't matter if you use SHA-3 or floss each day.

Comment: But what if I use SHA-3 and floss each day?